# how to check jTable nullpointer in row

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

how to check my jtable if null pointer?
my code is always null pointer and then can't export to xls.
this my code

```
if (tbGudangSales.getValueAt(i, 5).toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                        status = "tidak ada penjualan";
                    } else{
                        status = tbGudangSales.getValueAt(i, 5).toString();
                    }

                    label = new Label(4, baris, status, bordertabel);
                    excelSheet.addCell(label);
```

this my error
[image: Error null pointer]

this my value table
[image: Table]

Comment: Check if `tbGudangSales.getValueAt(i, 5) != null` before doing operations on whatever it returns

Comment: Put this condition too in your if loop `if (tbGudangSales.getValueAt(i, 5) == null || tbGudangSales.getValueAt(i, 5).toString().trim().length() == 0) {`

Comment: @Mark thx for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to check if the value is null. For example:

```
Object value = tbGudangSales.getValueAt(i, 5);

if (value != null)
{
    if(value.toString().trim().isEmpty()) // instead checking the length "manually", you can use the isEmpty() method
    {
        status = "tidak ada penjualan";
    } 
    else
    {
        status = value.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: thx for your help